# error: variable (date object) might not have been initialized

Tags: java, date

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   Date d;
   SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    try{
    d=sdf.parse("20-12-2016",0);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(d);
   }
}
```

When I compile this code I get

error: variable d might not have been initialized in

```
System.out.println(d);
```

but I have assigned it a date using parse function in

```
d=sdf.parse("20-12-2016",0);
```

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These here:

```
Date d;
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
try{
    d=sdf.parse("20-12-2016",0);
}
   catch(Exception ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

is a little bit dangerous, because if your try catch doesn't work, then you are passing a non initialized object as parameter (printing a date object that is not initialized)

the IDE is smart enough to prevent such thing, that is the reason it is complaining..

initialize the value when defining it.. 
and everything will be ok.

Comment: like Date d=new Date();?

Comment: yes, that could be a good init value....

Comment: It's not the IDE, it is the Java compiler. It is a property called *definite assignment*.

Comment: Yeah it is the java compiler@AndyTurner

Comment: you are right @AndyTurner, but some IDEs (like eclipse) will set warnings about it...

Comment: Date d=new Date(); is a waste of memory right? I am re assignining it in the next line itself@ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa

Comment: Failure to definitely assign a local variable results in an error, not a warning, since the JLS defines it as a compile-time error: "For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.". Eclipse's compiler cannot be any less strict than `javac`.

Comment: Guys when I changed the code as Date d=null; it works but I don't know how because it is still null